# Matching parameters with let/fn in Clojure

Tags: clojure, let

This is an example code from the book [Programming Clojure (2nd edition)](https://pragprog.com/book/shcloj2/programming-clojure) that calculates prime values.

```
(def primes
  (concat
   [2 3 5 7]
   (lazy-seq
    (let [primes-from
          (fn primes-from [n [f & r]]
            (if (some #(zero? (rem n %))
                      (take-while #(<= (* % %) n) primes))
              (recur (+ n f) r)
              (lazy-seq (cons n (primes-from (+ n f) r)))))
          wheel (cycle [2 4 2 4 6 2 6 4 2 4 6 6 2 6  4  2
                        6 4 6 8 4 2 4 2 4 8 6 4 6 2  4  6
                        2 6 6 4 2 4 6 2 6 4 2 4 2 10 2 10])]
      (primes-from 11 wheel)))))
```

The code has the structure that defines a local function `primes-from` to use that in the let form.

```
(def primes
  (concat
   [2 3 5 7]
   (lazy-seq
    (let [primes-from (fn primes-from [n [f & r]] ... ]
      (primes-from 11 wheel)))))
```

However, I'm not sure how the first parameter `11` and the second parameter `wheel` matches to the `[primes-from (fn primes-from [n [f & r]] ... ]` structure.

Also, I can't see how the `primes-from` parameter in defining anonymous function `(fn primes-from [n [f & r]]`.

Any explanations about this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `let` defines `primes-from` to refer to a function defined with `fn`.

When `primes-from` is first called, 11 matches `n`, and `wheel` matches `[f & r]`.  `wheel` refers to a sequence, and `[f & r]` expects a sequence--that's what the brackets mean.  `f` ("first") will match the first element in the sequence, which will be 2 the first time through.  The `&` means that the parameter after it, `r` ("rest") is intended to match the entire rest of the sequence (which starts with 4 the first time through).

(`cycle` defines a lazy sequence, so what matches `r` isn't fully expanded.)

Both "primes-from" in `(let [primes-from ...` and
"primes-from" in `(fn primes-from ...` are needed.  The first instance is what allows the initial call to the function in the last line of the definition of `primes`.  The second instance is what allows the recursive call to the function by name in the middle of the `fn` definition.  This last instance of "primes-from" also gives the function an internal name property that might be helpful during debugging.

(Note that there are two recursive calls within the `fn` definition.  The first uses `recur`, and the second uses `primes-from`.  Both could use `primes-from`, but it's generally better to use `recur`, when possible, because it doesn't use the stack and thus is more efficient and avoids running out of memory.  `recur` can only be used in tail position, i.e. when no further processing has to be done with the returned value within the function.  It's not possible to use `recur` in the second case, because the return value will be fed to `cons` and `lazy-seq`.)